# Including same #define in VS and Linux builds

Tags: c++, visual-c++, makefile, visual-studio-2005

I have a project that is compiled both under Linux and VS2005 and I need to pass a pack of definitions to C preprocessor during both builds (for example: MY_DEF1=1, MY_DEF2=2 etc.) The definitions are same in both builds.

Is there a way to tell VS2005 to include external build-time definitions?

Comment: Are you using a makefile to build in VS, or are you using a 'native' VS C++ project?

Comment: Why don't you write a `defs.h` file with `#define MY_DEF1 1`, etc. and then just `#include "defs.h"`?

Comment: Because I plan to use these definition also to affect make's behavior and need them to be in the Makefile's scope.

Answer (score 0):

In the VS C++ Project properties, there's an entry in:

```
Configuration Properties | C/C++ | Preprocessor | Preprocessor Definitions
```

where you can enter the defines (which can differ for each project configuration).

Answer (score 0):

You can use /D compiler option in the project makefile:

/DMY_DEF1=1

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8.aspx